# Should I use nameof to avoid repetition in constants?

Tags: c#

In C#, I sometimes use:

```
const string FirstName = "FirstName";
const string SSN = "SSN";

...

var ssn = GetValue(key: SSN);  // e.g. GetValue fetches value from some key/value store
```

to avoid hard-coding key strings throughout my code.  I'm thinking of taking advantage of C# 6.0 `nameof` to avoid the repetition in the `const` declaration, like so:

```
const object FirstName = null;
const object SSN = null;

...

var ssn = GetValue(key: nameof(SSN));
```

Is this a proper use of `nameof`?  Is there a better way to avoid repetition in `const` declarations?

Comment: It has the huge disadvantage that now renaming your variable will destroy persistent data.

Comment: Your original code had the disadvantage that it was unclear if it should be used as `GetValue(key: SSN)` or as `GetValue(key: nameof(SSN))`. Also, the peculiar value-equals-identifier pattern could be confused for an ordinary string const (where the value is different from the name). What I like about the other code is that a `const` of type `object` (or `object?` as it is sometimes known since 2019 (nullable reference types)) can hardly be used accidentally because not many receivers accept an `object` in modern C#. So such a `const` signals clearly that it is only useful for `nameof()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about an enumeration? (thanks to @JoelFan for pointing out the Enum [ToString method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16c1xs4z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

```
var value = GetValue(Keys.SSN.ToString());
```

And of course you would define an enumeration with each of your keys.

```
enum Keys
{
    SSN, FirstName 
}
```

Comment: Why do you need an extension method like that?  Can't you just call ToString on any Enum?

Comment: Huh. [looks like you can](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16c1xs4z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - I'm not working on the project where we did that before so I can't go check to see if I'm remembering something wrong or we were out to lunch. Anyway you're right, no need for the extension method.

Comment: Surely this has exactly the same weakness as using `nameof`: refactoring the name of any of the enum's members will break any persisted data structure that uses the old string values. I'm not saying don't use this technique, just to be aware of the tradeoffs (ie. don't use if you're planning on persisting these enum values anywhere).

Comment: Yes, you're right. However, I think a well placed comment could do the trick - it's just a matter of communicating with all future devs that the enum needs to match the data storage. There would be other clues, like if you named the enum `KeysForTheDataStorage`, or a quick check of the usages shows that it's always used for `GetValue(KeysForTheDataStorage.SSN.ToString())`. The bottom line is that string keys for value lookup in a strongly typed language will be somewhat brittle no matter what you do.

Comment: You could still use `nameof` with the enum, like `GetValue(nameof(Keys.SSN))`. There is the (tiny?) advantage that `nameof()` gives a compile-time constant that is "burned" into the IL at compile-time; in contrast `.ToString()` on an enum will be resolved each time at run-time.

Answer (score 3):

No. You've made the contract of the SSN constant really weak- it's completely non-obvious what it's for.

You could use nameof in the definition but that would still look pretty similar to your original code.

```
const string FirstName = nameof(FirstName);
const string SSN = nameof(SSN);
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone else has mentioned this, but I really think an `Enum` is the tool for the job here. [Here is a detailed explanation of when and why they can be useful.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3712403/2762475) It's a good design choice over many other constant/key options for performance, extensibility, readability, etc.

If I understand what you're trying to do, an `Enum` is doing exactly what you intend with your off-label use of `nameof`: A constant that is *only* a name. I like the term "strongly-typed constant" to describe the concept of an `Enum`. Off the top of my head...

```
// Note: Enum names should describe a generic member, so avoid names like IDs/KeyCollection/PersonalData
public Enum Identifier
{
 FirstName, SSN, Fingerprint, Retina, OtherKey, FinalKey
}
// ...
var ssn = GetValue(SSN);

// Other considerations vs const string keys:
string[] AllMyConstants = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Identifier)); // Collections and parsing to/from strings built-in
////Identifier.SSN = "Compiler error will save me from trying to change a constant."

// Bonus thing I just learned: System.Enum uses ints underneath, so you can get imaginative defining enums as ints:
public Enum BasketballPosition {PG = 1, SG = 2, SF = 3, PF = 4, C = 5};
public Enum Grade {F = 0, D = 60, C = 70, B = 80, A = 90};  
public Enum DifficultyFactor {Easy = 1, Medium = 10, Hard = 100, Insane = 1000};
public Enum Transaction {Deposit = 1, Withdrawal = -1, Transfer = 0};
public Enum MilestoneDay {Conceived = -270, Born = 0, FirstBirthday = 365, EighteenthBirthday = 6570};
```